# Android Preferenceactivity getView

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have such piece of code :)
And i want to edit text property of my custom preference layout.
But any changes made on object from getView function does not affect actual list in preference screen. any ideas? I know that i cant extend PreferenceScreen, and i cant use any other type of preference in this case, i only want to be able to edit my custom textview from my layout in code.

```
PreferenceScreen settings = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

settings.setLayoutResource(R.layout.mypreference);
View test = (View) settings.getView(null,getListView());

TextView text = (TextView)test.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("BLA BLA");
```

Answer (score 8):

We ***should*** be using [`getView(convertView, parent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) but from countless ***unanswered*** questions on StackOverflow, it's obvious no one knows how to use it. So our only option is to create a custom `Preference`:

**Create a new Class:**

```java
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {
    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View rootView) {
        super.onBindView(rootView);

        View myView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
        // do something with myView
    }
}
```

**In your** `xml/preferences.xml`, add your custom preference:

```xml
<your.package.name.CustomPreference
    android:key="custom_preference"
    android:layout="@layout/custom_layout" />
```

Comment: Am I the only one with onBindView NEVER called?

Answer (score 0):

Using the custom layout below:

custom_preferences_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/preview_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/notification_preview" />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Using the file above with your user preferences xml file, you can do this to access the items in your custom layout:

```
public class CustomPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.custom_preferences);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_preferences_layout);
    }

    private void initCustomizePreferences(){
        //Button
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.preview_button);
        //Do something with the button.

    }

}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onBindView` in your custom `Preference` class.

More details -
[Get view of preference with custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233440/get-view-of-preference-with-custom-layout/26074821#26074821)

Answer (score -2):

I never actually messed with the views of a PreferenceActivity, but here's something I do (usually for ListPreferences)

```
ListPreference listPref;
CheckBoxPreference cbPref;

// Set the summary as the current listpref value
listPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("list_pref_key");
listPref.setSummary(listPref.getEntry()); 

// change the title / summary / ??? of any preference
findPreference("anothe_pref_key").setTitle("New Title");
findPreference("anothe_pref_key").setSummary("New subtext for the view");
```

This way, even if the layout used by PreferenceActivity / PreferenceFragment change in a future version, you wont have to change anything in your code.

Comment: ok but how to change custom element, title and summary are default android methods for any preference, and there are methods for filling them like settitle and setsummary, but how to edit other id's?

Comment: What kind of other id do you want to change ? Because usually in a preferenceScreen, you only have the title and summary

Comment: yes and i have my own custom layout set by setLayoutResource, in this layout there are some additional fields other than title and summary, setting text value to textview in xml works ok, but i need to change font on this textview, and i cant do it via xml

Comment: I think that the getView may recreate a view and not return the view being displayed. If you're in a PreferenceActivity, try using findViewById(R.id.text); instead of test.findViewById(R.id.text);