# Get view of preference with custom layout

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preference android:layout gft.
I've set the layout in the android:layout property of the preference in the xml file.

Now I need to do an initialization of a button in the layout (it's a +1 button).
I need to get that button in the onCreate method (it's a +1 button) but when I use `findViewById(button_id)` , it returns null.

Is there some way to get the view of this preference?

**UPDATE:**  It seems like the preference isn't created after I add the preference xml, so I get null. Where I can call findViewById so the button is already created?

Thanks.

Preferences xml:

```
<Preference android:title="Rate this app"
    android:key="rate"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/plusone_pref"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Preference layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:focusable="false"
plus:size="standard" />
```

Comment: You can add the custom layout after the preferences.xml is inflated. 
Like
((listView.parent as FrameLayout).parent as LinearLayout).addView(customView,0)

listView is a recyclerView from androidx.preferences.R.id.recycler_view

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create a class that extends `Preference`, then override `onBindView` and you'll have access to the view.

```
public class MyPreference extends Preference {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        View myView = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.my_id);
        // ... do stuff
    }

}
```

You'll probably have to override some more methods, read about custom preference in PreferenceActivity - 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html