# How to access button in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I created button in Preferences in this way:

```
 <PreferenceScreen>
    <Preference
    android:key="resetBD"
    android:title="@string/ajustes_almacenamiento"
    android:summary="@string/ajustes_almacenamiento_desc"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/pref_reset_bd_button" >
    </Preference>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

layout/pref_reset_bd_button.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/submit_layout_button"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:weightSum="10">
 <Button
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/resetButton"
  android:text="Reset"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:onClick="submitWifiToDevice"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

In PreferenceFragment I successfuly access/get the button doing this:

```
        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.pref_reset_bd_button, null, false);
        resetButton= (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
```

But when I try to change button text

```
resetButton.setText("NEW ONE");
```

(or disable) nothing happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to refresh the screen before it is visible. Sorry from head i do not know how at the moment.

Comment: are you putting setText under any if condition?

Comment: I see in android-studio debuger that button get new text but it not update in emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Create a custom Preference:

```
public class PreferenceWidget extends Preference {
    private View mView;

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        mView = view.findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    }

    public View getView() {
        return mView;
    }
}
```

Then change your preference xml

```
 <PreferenceScreen>
    <package.PreferenceWidget 
    android:key="resetBD"
    android:title="@string/ajustes_almacenamiento"
    android:summary="@string/ajustes_almacenamiento_desc"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/pref_reset_bd_button" >
    </package.PreferenceWidget >
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

Then to get the view

```
PreferenceWidget p = (PreferenceWidget)findPreference("resetBD");
Button b = (Button)p.getView();
b.setText("Hello");
```

**Original answer:**

You shouldn't have to inflate the View yourself. This should happen in your call to addPreferencesFromResource.

Then you can get the preference, get the preference's view, find the button view, then set the text.

```
Preference p = findPreference("resetBD");
View v = p.getView(null, null);
Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
v.setText("Hello");
```

Although, since [no one seems to know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28207227/1943229) how to use the [Preference.getView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) function you may have to create a custom Preference object.

Comment: It's the same... In android-studio debuger I obtained button and set new text successfully, but in emulator button text doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change. I can change preferences title for example, but not content of widgetLayout